# Sharing Gemfile.lock between JRuby and MRI

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I'm developing a gem that is compatible with JRuby and MRI without cross-compiling. I discovered that running `bundle install` on JRuby [changes `Gemfile.lock`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKdSr.png).

And when I run `bundle install` on MRI, `Gemfile.lock` doesn't change back. But everything goes as expected. MRI bundler didn't try to install the new dependencies added by JRuby.

How does bundler know that it shouldn't install those even if I didn't mention it?

Is it safe to have a single `Gemfile.lock` for both JRuby and MRI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's fine and what you want. re-running `bundle` under MRI will be OK. so simply commit that into git and maybe re-run bundle under both Rubies when its changed.

support for having gem dependencies relative to platform (as some gems might be native) has landed around Bundler 1.16 so make sure you're not using an older version.